# Link prepended to div with jQuery can't be used as selector for another bind

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement a feature where you can pin elements from the main content area into a smaller div. This feature works as expected.

```
$('.pin').bind('click', function() {
  $('#sbStar').prepend($(this).parent().parent().parent('.leaf').clone(true));
});
```

EDIT: Changing clone() to clone(true), as per Vega's suggestion, fixed my earlier problem (below), but has not resolved it completely. Now I am trying to get the expand button to do a different behaviour depending on whether it is in #sbStar or is in the main content area. Unfortunately, this ('#sbStar .expand') still doesn't work.

```
$('#sbStar .expand').bind('click', function() {
  console.log('expand');
});
```

For Reference, the HTML:

```
<article class="leaf">
  <footer>
    <aside class="left">
      <a href="#" class="expand">E</a>
      <a href="#sbStar" class="pin">P</a>
    </aside>
  </footer>
</article>
```

Original Issue:
    $('.expand').bind('click', function() {
      console.log('expand');
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the following to fix your issue,

a. Use `clone(true)` - The true indicates whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements.

b. Bind the event handler function after the `clone`.

```
function myHanlder() {  console.log('expand'); }

.clone().bind('click', myHandler);
```

c. Use delegated events.

```
$('#sbStar').on ('click', '.expand', function () { ... });
```

Comment: clone(true) should fix it, and delegated events (using on() instead of bind()) would as well (typically, in a dynamic environment, using delegated events is preferred as you never have to worry about losing events)